# XML to Java JaxB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

My attempt to convert an XML to Java using JAXB not working as expected. There are multiple other similar questions around it but none of the suggested solutions I looked into seem to help me.

Below is my bean

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ListingResponse", namespace = "http://www.random.com")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"success", "listingId", "description"})
public class ListingResponse {
    private String success;
    private String listingId;
    private String description;


    public String getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "Success")
    public void setSuccess(String success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public String getListingId() {
        return listingId;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "ListingId")
    public void setListingId(String listingId) {
        this.listingId = listingId;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "Description")
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
```

Below is my attempt to do the unmarshaling

```
ListingResponse response = null;
try {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ListingResponse.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    response = (ListingResponse) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("response.xml"));

} catch (JAXBException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And finally my response.xml content

```
<ListingResponse xmlns="http://www.random.com" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Success>true</Success>
    <Description>ListingId 123 created.</Description>
    <ListingId>123</ListingId>
</ListingResponse>
```

1. There are not exceptions being thrown.
2. '`response`' is NOT null.
3. I have tried adding `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD / PROPERTY)`
   with `@XMLEelement` annotation on the fields/ set methods but that didn't seem to help either.

However, response is always 'empty' with none of the fields initialized.

Can you guys spot the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you only have specified the correct namespace qualification for the root element. You need to use the package level `@XmlSchema` annotation to map the namespace qualification for your model.

**package-info.java**

```
@XmlSchema( 
    namespace = "http://www.random.com", 
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED) 
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: Thanks. I have to admit, this info was already in your blog except I didn't even know how to create package-info.java before this!!!